# Selecting distinct dates from datetime column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
id | message | date_posted
1  | testing | 2011-03-08 03:15:13
2  | testing | 2011-03-06 03:15:13
3  | testing | 2011-03-08 03:15:13
```

And need a query where I return a list of distinct dates in desc order. I tried to formulate a query like so

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(`date_posted` AS DATE) AS dateonly FROM table
```

This gives me dates but they're not distinct and have duplicates.

Any ideas? (Using php/mysql)

**MAJOR EDIT:**

Forgot an important piece of information. I'm trying to get unique dates based on month and year.

```
2011-03-08 03:15:13
2011-03-06 03:15:13
2011-03-02 03:15:13
2011-03-01 03:15:13
2011-02-01 03:15:13
```

So running the query would only return [2011-03-dd,2011-02-01] (dd being any day)

Apologize for not stating this.

Comment: That query works for me - have you simplified your query? Post your full query

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your query will return unique DATES, as you've specified. If you want to get just unique MONTHS/YEARS, you should either modify you dates in a way, that each date becomes the first day of the month, or you should just go with some string representation like 'YYYY-MM'. Sorry, I can't write you an exact code how to do this, as I do not develop on mysql, but I think this should get you somewhere :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date_posted), MONTH(date_posted) FROM table
```

Comment: Ended up using this solution, thank you. Richard aka cyberkiwi's solution worked as well.

Answer (score 9):

Working example

```
create table dts (dt datetime);
insert dts select '2011-03-08 03:15:13';
insert dts select '2011-03-07 03:15:13';
insert dts select '2011-03-09 03:15:13';
insert dts select '2011-03-08 03:15:13';

select distinct cast(dt as date) from dts;
```

Output

```
"cast(dt as date)"
"2011-03-08"
"2011-03-07"
"2011-03-09"
```

Query for distinct Year-Month

```
select date(date_format(dt, '%Y-%m-1')) as dt
from dts
group by dt;
```

Output (the result is a date column, with the day set to '1')

```
2011-03-01
```

Comment: I made a major edit in my post, apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT DATE(`date_posted`) AS dateonly 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY DATE(`date_posted`)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be grabbing unique dates, same effect as my original query.

Comment: Show us your full table schema, and sample data, and use the query exactly as it is. This must work.

Comment: Please read my update, I forgot to add a major condition. Your query definitely works for what I asked, I just forgot to mention an extra detail.

Comment: I don't see the difference. I don't understand it. Please explain more, and give example what should not be included.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(date_format(COLUMN_NAME, '%Y-%m-%d')) as uniquedates from TABLE_NAME
```